# Is there a C equivalent of a Python next() on a file pointer?

Tags: python, c

In Python, one can express the idea that one wants to advance the file pointer to the next line (without reading the data) by using `next(myfile)`.

In C, the only way I see for doing this (without knowing beforehand the exact number of characters in the line to be skipped) is to allocate a buffer of size equal to the maximum line length, and call the `fgets` function as follows. `fseek` seems to require knowing the file position as an offset.

```
 char buffer[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
 fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE_SIZE, file_ptr)
```

Is there a more elegant way to move one line forward in a file in C? 
I would be particularly interested in solutions that do not require an extra buffer.

Comment: Python _does_ read the data, and `next(file)` returns the string. If you don't save a reference to it, the string just becomes available for garbage collection immediately.

Comment: Touche. I did not actually read the docs on `next`, but rather just saw it often in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, there is no direct equivalent of this functionality in the C library.

The trick with `fgets` has a weakness - you need to know the maximum length of a line in your file, or add a loop around `fgets`.

If you do not want any of the characters from the current position up to and including the end-of-line marker, you can use `fgetc`, like this:

```
int next;
while ((next=fgetc(file_ptr)) != EOF && (next != '\n'))
   ; // <<== Do nothing
// At this point your file_ptr is either at the next line or at EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a buffer.  You may read every char till you get the new line char \n

FILE

```
 test.txt
 line1word1 line1word2 line1word3
 line2word1
 line3word1 line3word2
```

CODE

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_line(FILE* file);
void jump_to_next_line(FILE* file);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE* file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (!file) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    print_line(file);
    jump_to_next_line(file);
    print_line(file);
}

void print_line(FILE* file) {
    unsigned char c;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != '\n' && !feof(file)) {
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void jump_to_next_line(FILE* file) {
    while (fgetc(file) != '\n' && !feof(file));
}
```

RESULT

```
line1word1 line1word2 line1word3
line3word1 line3word2
```